# Foods.filter is not a function- Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

i am trying to a multiple deletion by selecting checkboxes but i get the error **Foods.filter is not a function** error in my console when i try to make a multiple deletion. When i introduced the pipe in the html table, that was when the error was raised. But without the pipe, it works fine. Could it be that the filter is not receiving the array?

**html**

```
 <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let key of Foods | keys; let i = index" >
          <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
          <td><input  #{{Foods[key].id}} [(ngModel)]="Foods[key].selected" type="checkbox"></td>

    </tbody>
```

**component**

```
delete() {
    this.RemoveFood = this.Foods.filter(Foods => Foods.selected);
    for (var food in this.RemoveFood) {
        this.httpService.deleteFood(this.RemoveFood[food].id)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Foods` is an Object, not an array. I guess the `keys` pipe returns `Object.keys(input)`.

Comment: meaning the keys doesn't return an Object ?

Comment: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array containing the object keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Food seems to be an Object and not an array, so there is no `filter` method implemented.

```
delete() {
    Object.keys(this.Foods) //get an array of the object keys
    .filter(key => this.Foods[key].selected) //filter selected foods
    .forEach(key=>{ //for each food, delete
      let id= this.Foods[key].id;
      this.httpService.deleteFood(id);
    });
}
```

Note that it might be long to remove several foods one by one, maybe you should think to a batch delete method on the server.

Comment: the delete() functions seems not to trigger anything. I consoled logged the data but nothing appears

Comment: consolelogged what data ? where ?

Comment: well when i consolelogged the id,  i get the ids of the selected of the foods but this line    **this.httpService.deleteFood(id);** seems not to run

Comment: If you can log the id just before, yes it is.

Comment: the selected food don't delete

Comment: I guess you are returning an observable then.... You should `subscribe()`, then, but creating many subscription is bad practice. However, it's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Even with subscription, nothing happens

Comment: Also note that I don't have any idea about what happen in your code elsewhere, maybe you need to update the `Foods` object, maybe you must `this.httpService.deleteFood(id).subscribe ();`, I don't know because I only have 11 lines of your code.

Comment: got it!! Thanks anyway